# Site with FBA Accounts Not Sending Emails from Designer Workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, forms-authentication, outgoing-email

I have a new external site in 2013 configured with FBA. On a list, I have a Designer workflow that does the following:

1. Email an address directly
2. Email a FBA account (that has an email address affiliated with it)
3. Email the "Created By" user for the item

1 succeeds, while 2 and 3 fail and both log in the history:
"The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the outgoing e-mail settings for the server are configured correctly."

Out-going email settings are set in Central Admin, and another external site configured with FBA on the same farm has no problem with any of these emailing examples. What could be improperly set on the new site that's stopping certain emails (with the only connection being to FBA accounts) from going through?

Comment: is it 2013 workflows or 2010 designer workflow and same question for working site? are the same users work in working site workflow? are the users are in your UPA?

Comment: I'm using a 2010 Workflow (in 2013 Designer). The same fba users work when emailed from an identical workflow on the other site. I believe they should be in UPA, though I'm not sure how to verify that part.

Comment: Just a thought, but, in the `Send Email` action, did you set the `Return field as` to `Email adress`?

Comment: @douvillema in action #2 in my post, I just add a FBA user under "Selected Users" in the To field of an Email message, and it doesn't prompt me for the "return field as"

Comment: I think you will get this option only with your action #3. Can you try and verify the #3? I'm not sure for the #2 though.

Comment: For action #3, in the Select Users prompt for the To field, I select "User who created current item" and click "Add >>" then "OK". I am not prompted for the "return field as" on this either.

Answer (score 0):

Is the other site operating on a different server in the farm? If that's the case, then the problem will be that your configured SMTP server is not setup to allow relaying from that SharePoint server - that's why internal email addresses will go through but external email addresses will not.  This is a setting on the SMTP server itself - it will have to whitelist the ip address of your SharePoint server to allow relaying.

Comment: This site is operating on the same server as the other that is working without a problem.

Comment: To add more detail, let's say I'm in SP Designer adding an email to a workflow. On the site with no problems, if I were to type my email in the "Type a Name or E-mail Address" field of the "Select Users" dialog and hit "Add>>" on the site with no issues, the "Selected Users" field populates with my FBA name. On the site with issues, doing the same would populate "Selected Users" with the email address I typed, no username recognition. Where could that specific site be missing a "link" to FBA usernames and emails?

Comment: This just means that on the other site the SharePoint user profile for the fba user has been filled out.  I guess that possibly might be what's causing the problem, if your sharepoint user profile doesn't have an email address attached to it.  If you install the FBA Pack you can use the user management page to edit the user profile for existing FBA users - changes will get saved the to the sharepoint user profile. Try saving the changes for a user and then reattempt sending email for that user.